# Etiquetas con versiones específicas de python

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

En python tenemos ahora mismo las siguientes etiquetas:

- [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (~4400 preguntas)
- [python-2.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) (69 preguntas)
- [python-2.7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) (500 preguntas)
- [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (1599 preguntas)
- [python3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3), aparentemente es un sinónimo de la anterior, pues tiene el mismo número de preguntas.
- [python-3.7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.7) (1 pregunta) Esto probablemente se trata de un error

Creo que tantas etiquetas para un solo lenguaje entorpece más de lo que ayuda. Es cierto que python incorpora en algunas versiones características específicas que no son aplicables a otras versiones, pero en muchos casos puede combinarse la etiqueta [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) con la etiqueta de la característica en cuestión. Por ejemplo, los *keywords* `async/await` se introducen en python 3.5, creo que puede ser más claro usar las etiquetas `python` y `async` para preguntas sobre este tema, que no una hipotética `python-3.5`. Además probablemente quien formula la pregunta no sepa en qué versión de python particular se introdujo esa característica.

Sí que veo necesario mantener al menos las etiquetas [python-2.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) y [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) pues las diferencias entre estas ramas son muy profundas hasta el punto de que el código de una puede ser incompatible con el de la otra.

En definitiva mi propuesta es dejar sólo tres etiquetas en python, que serían [python-2.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x), [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) y [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (esta última la veo como un mal necesario).

Lo que no tengo muy claro es la operativa para acometer esta reducción:

- ¿Hacer que [python-2.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) sea un alias de [python-2.7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7)? Esto solo resuelve en parte el problema pues las etiquetas siguen existiendo ¿seguirían siendo sugeridas a los usuarios que formulan preguntas?
- "Borrar" (si es que se puede) una de las etiquetas? ¿Qué pasa con las preguntas que la llevaban? ¿Pueden re-etiquetarse automáticamente?

Comment: De acuerdo en que muchas veces la etiqueta específica es innecesaria. Lo que sí creo útil es tener etiquetas específicas cuando convenga. Por ejemplo, la que comentas de [tag:python-3.7] la puse yo ayer para [¿Cómo puedo instalar la libreria tensoflow en Python 3.7?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/208171/83), igual que una pregunta sobre los futuros [_assignment statement_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51185782/1983854) solamente debería tener [tag:python-3.8] pues es en esta minor donde se introducirá. Lo mismo con python-2.7 y muchas cosas que python-2.6 aún no tenía.

Comment: considero que al preguntar al ver la etiqueta python, solicitar la version y actualizar la pregunta  con la etiqueta de version correspondiente, eso lo haremos los que tenemos tiempo, que pasa con los nuevos usuarios, como hariamos?

Comment: Tu quieres quemar las etiquetas??

Answer (score 5):

Concuerdo con la proposición de dejar sólo python-2.x, python-3.x y python.

En dos años respondiendo Python en SOes, me habré topado con menos de 10 preguntas donde la versión era relevante. Normalmente eran problemas derivados de incompatibilidades entre 2.x y 3.x.

Python 2 está prácticamente muerto. Todas las preguntas suponen un escenario de Python 3. Las diferencias entre 3.1 y 3.10, son mínimas, acotadas y particulares.

No veo ninguna consecuencia negativa en la proposición.