# ¿Debo usar la etiqueta [python-3.x] para una pregunta que habla de algo introducido en Python 3.8?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Hace poco creé la pregunta auto-respondida [¿Cómo se utiliza el operador morsa?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/453785/c%C3%B3mo-se-utiliza-el-operador-morsa) y a la hora de etiquetarla me surgió la siguiente duda.

Para el que no quiera leerla, la pregunta trata sobre un operador introducido en la versión 3.8 de `Python`, por lo que al ir a poner la etiqueta [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) me surgió la duda de si era correcto utilizarla, ya que esa etiqueta también vale para versiones anteriores pero no para mi pregunta. Pero por otro lado también vale para la versión 3.8 en adelante, así que no sé si es correcto su uso en estos casos.

Al final opté por editar mi pregunta e incluir la etiqueta [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) por ser más genérica, y dejé las dos, pero no tengo muy claro qué sería lo correcto.

He leído la pregunta en Meta [Etiquetas con versiones específicas de python](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/etiquetas-con-versiones-espec%C3%ADficas-de-python), donde en los comentarios fedorqui propone utilizar la etiqueta [python-3.8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.8), pero es una pregunta que no tiene respuestas y además es antigua, por lo que no ha terminado de resolver mi duda.

¿Hay algún criterio para casos así?

**Edición**

En un comentario @fedorqui me ha hecho ver que ya había una publicación similar a la que yo hice, por lo que considero que debo eliminar la mía (una pena para mi, pues es una de mis publicaciones con más votos y me cuesta horrores conseguirlos) pero independientemente sigo sin entender cómo buscando por `operador morsa` esta pregunta no me apareció, ya que es el nombre por el que se le conoce popularmente. De hecho en la pregunta lo llaman así pero en su versión en ingles `wallrus`.

Como ya he dicho, eliminaré la pregunta (a menos que se me diga lo contrario) ya que la que existía tiene una buena respuesta. Pero de todas formas creo que debería incluirse `operador morsa` de alguna manera en ella, ya sea como etiqueta o editandola.

También en mi respuesta añado alguna cosa que no se ha dicho, por lo que no sé si lo correcto sería añadirla como respuesta también a esa pregunta y si eso ya de paso soluciona la búsqueda con `operador morsa`.

@fedirqui, considero la pregunta duplicada, y así lo marcaré, pero voy a esperar a que me respondáis a esto antes de hacerlo.

Comment: [tag:python] debe ponerse siempre, pues es el "paraguas" que incluye todo sobre este lenguaje. [tag:python-3.8] también, pues sería algo válido a partir de esta versión concreta. En lo que tengo dudas es en si ponerle también [tag:python-3.x] o no: como bien dices, no es algo que aplique a todas las versiones; a priori, yo optaría por no ponerla, pero tampoco tengo criterio claro.

Comment: Fíjate de hecho en lo útil que es poner las etiquetas: una pregunta muy similar ya fue publicada hace un año y tiene [tag:python-3.8]; de haberla puesto en la tuya, seguramente te la habría sugerido como duplicada. Y es que las etiquetas están para eso, para ordenar y facilitar que se puedan encontrar.

Comment: Sobre tu edición: ¡no la borres! Tu pregunta-respuesta es buena y útil. Además, como se ha visto en este caso, contiene un texto que la otra no, por lo que resulta un buen punto de acceso para encontrar contenido útil. La otra habla de "walrus" y tu usas la versión en castellano, "morsa". Yo la encontré buscando `[python*] code:":="`. Sobre añadir etiquetas, adelante; yo en lugar de publicar otra respuesta en la otra, tal vez ampliaría la respuesta que ya tiene, creando una respuesta canónica. Esto ya como veas.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Pensaba que al ser duplicada, había que eliminarlas. Ya he modificado las etiqueta, quitando al final la de 3.x y añadiendo 3.8.